# Propose to merge [procmail] and [.procmailrc]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I propose merging [procmail](/questions/tagged/procmail) and [.procmailrc](/questions/tagged/.procmailrc) on Stack Overflow; they have 35 and 7 questions respectively. When i searched about procmail format language, I used [procmail](/questions/tagged/procmail). Both tags still have tiny amount of questions, and they will not have much more in future because not too many people use procmail. For a long time I used maildrop as MDA, and it doesn't even have a tag on Stack Overflow.

Is it a good proposal?